# How to generate a random matrix which have given singular values?

Tags: numerical-methods, random, numerical-linear-algebra, random-matrices

I know one method: generate a random matrix, apply SVD decomposition, modify singular values, and then multiply those matrices back together.

However, I'm wondering how random this method is.

Since [this paper](http://home.lu.lv/~sd20008/papers/essays/Random%20unitary%20%5Bpaper%5D.pdf) claims that one can generate random unitary matrices **uniformly** from $U(n)$, which is the set of all the unitary matrices of order $n$.

Is there a method which can generate a random matrix with given singular values **uniformly** from all matrices with same set of singular values?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why to compute the SVD? You can use simple the QR factorization to orthogonalize a random (most likely full rank) matrix.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: Because here I want to generate random matrices with given singular values. Of course, we can use QR factorization to generate two "random" unitary matrices then use $Q_1DQ_2$ to get the random matrix we want, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with given singular values as diagonal. However, this method can not guarantee the uniformity of the "randomness" either.

Comment: I don't say it is a "random enough" approach. I just found a bit strange to generate a random orthogonal matrix using SVD.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: But I'm not generating random orthogonal matrices.... Thank you all the same for your advice on generating orthogonal matrices. :)